# Inconsistent dtype inference for mixed floats and strings

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-dtype

```py
np.array([5.3, 1.2, 76.1, 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire'])
```

I am wondering why this give a dtype of dtype=U32, however the following code gives a dtype of U6.

```py
np.array(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire', 5.3, 1.2, 76.1])
```

Comment: `np.array` is a compiled function, so we can't readily look at what it's doing.  We can only guess from the results.  It may be guessing based on initial values, and refining that guess as it encounters new values.  Initial numbers, float or integer, do produce longer character dtypes.  But why worry about this? You shouldn't be using this style of array construction in cases where memory matters.

Comment: Try `np.array([np.int32(2), 'alice'])` and other dtypes.  The `U` length varies with the `int/uint` size, but floats all seem to produce `U32`.  Evidently some developer chose that as a safe value, and no one has bothered to refine choice.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy tries to be efficient when storing datatypes by calculating how many bits it will take to store an object.

```
import np
a = np.array([5.3, 1.2, 76.1, 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire'])
b = np.array(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire', 5.3, 1.2, 76.1])
print(a.dtype, b.dtype)

>>> <U32 <U6
```

Numpy sees `5.3` and puts it into a datatype which is a 32-codepoint data-type due to the datatype conversion rules:

> Type of the data (integer, float, Python object, etc.)
>
> Size of the data (how many bytes is in e.g. the integer)
>
> Byte order of the data (little-endian or big-endian)
>
> If the data type is structured data type, an aggregate of other data
>   types, (e.g., describing an array item consisting of an integer and a
>   float),
>
> what are the names of the “fields” of the structure, by which they can
>   be accessed,
>
> what is the data-type of each field, and
>
> which part of the memory block each field takes.
>
> If the data type is a sub-array, what is its shape and data type.

When it sees the other strings in the array, they can fit within the 32-codepoint data-type and so it doesn't have to be changed.

Now, consider the second example. Numpy sees `Alice` and puts it into a datatype which can hold six bits. Numpy continues along and sees `5.3`, which can also be fit into a 6-codepoint data-type. So no upgrading is required.

Similarly, when running `np.array(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Claire', 5.3, 1.2, 76.1, 'Bobby', 2.3000000000001])` it results in a `U15` as Numpy sees `2.3000000000001` and finds out that the datatype that it is using is not large enough to hold `2.3000000000001` and then upgrades it.

https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes

Comment: _"Numpy sees 5.3 and puts it into a datatype which is a 32-codepoint data-type"_ is surprising when compared to _"Numpy continues along and sees 5.3, which can also be fit into a 6-codepoint data-type"_. You're probably right that it's happening, but this doesn't really go very far into why.